# Display Toast without using useEffect to control the state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I tried to add Toast from `react-bootstrap` into my application and I can make the functionality works with following code. However
I am wondering if it is redundant to use `useEffect` to set show by `setShow(items.length > 0);`? Would it be just easier to do something like `const show = items.length > 0;` or any better way for me to approach?

```
example of fetch response
{
  "items": [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Apples",  "price": "$2" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Peaches", "price": "$5" }
  ] 
}

import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Toast } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(items.length > 0);
  }, [items]);
  // const show = items.length > 0? maybe?
  const toggleShowB = () => setShow(!show);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Toast onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={show} delay={3000} autohide>
        <Toast.Header />
        <Toast.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a Toast!</Toast.Body>
      </Toast>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is good question

### Let's break down the order of operations for what you have:

1. On mount, the first useEffect will fetch and call `setItems`
2. This state change will trigger one re-render and update `items`
3. The second useEffect will then run since `items` is a dependency and call `setShow`.
4. This is another state change and will trigger a re-render to update `show`
5. Your Toast will then show (if `items.length > 0`)

#### Alternatively, without the second effect

1. On mount, the first useEffect will fetch and call `setItems`
2. This state change will trigger one re-render and update `items`
3. Your Toast will then show if `show={items.length > 0}`

#### Conclusion

You save yourself a re-render by not using the second useEffect to update a `show` state variable.

Comment: so if I just use `show={items.length > 0}` how can I write this line `  const [show, setShow] = useState(false); so I can only use setShow but not show?
`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using another useEffect hook, you can just use:

```
<Toast onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={items.length > 0 && show} delay={3000} autohide>
```

You can force it to close by changing the show. This works because react rerenders it every time `items` changes.

#### Edit

if you do not want to close it forcefully, just remove the && show.

```
<Toast show={items.length > 0} delay={3000} autohide>
```

Comment: hm...can you explain a little bit show variable is`false` as initial value then at which point `items.length > 0 && show` will return true?

Comment: if show is false, it would not show, you can remove this if you never wnat to foce hide it. /:

Comment: yes, so my question is `show={items.length > 0 && show}` show will be always false since show state never set as true if I do not use second useEffect

Comment: I added that because `onClose={() => setShow(false)}` so i thought you needed it. if you dont need it, remove it.